Rolebinding a Clusterrole with complete access is deleting namespace
I have a clusterrole with complete access rule and a rolebinding to individual namespaces. Though full access clusterrole is binded to a rolebinding in a namespace, I thought..! user will have complete access to only resources under the namespace, but not to namespace itself.
User is able to delete namespace too. How can I restrict him in deleting the namespace "test".
Clusterrole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: namespace-fullaccess
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'

Rolebinding to test namespace
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: test-binding
  namespace: test
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: namespace-fullaccess
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: user
  namespace: serviceaccounts

Log:
$ kubectl describe  clusterrole namespace-fullaccess
Name:         namespace-fullaccess
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources  Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------  -----------------  --------------  -----
  *.*        []                 []              [*]
  
$ kubectl describe  rolebinding  -n test
Name:         test-binding
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  namespace-fullaccess
Subjects:
  Kind            Name    Namespace
  ----            ----    ---------
  ServiceAccount  user  serviceaccounts
  
$ kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                              CLUSTER    AUTHINFO                          NAMESPACE
*         user-serviceaccounts-dev          dev        user-serviceaccounts-dev          serviceaccounts

$ kubectl auth can-i delete namesapce/test
Warning: the server doesn't have a resource type 'namespace'

no

$ kubectl delete ns test
namespace "test" deleted

Other RBAC rules for the service account "User"
For complete cluster read access to Service Account "User"
$ kubectl describe  clusterrole cluster-readonly
Name:         cluster-readonly
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources  Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------  -----------------  --------------  -----
  *.*        []                 []              [get watch list]
  
$ kubectl describe  clusterrolebinding  cluster-readonly
Name:         cluster-readonly
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  cluster-readonly
Subjects:
  Kind            Name     Namespace
  ----            ----     ---------
  ServiceAccount  user  serviceaccounts

Access to cluster level resources to Service account "User"
$ kubectl describe  clusterrole custom-access
Name:         custom-access
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
PolicyRule:
  Resources                    Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names                                                  Verbs
  ---------                    -----------------  --------------                                                  -----
  clusterrolebindings.*        []                 []                                                              [create bind escalate]
  clusterroles.*               []                 []                                                              [create bind escalate]
  customresourcedefinitions.*  []                 []                                                              [create bind escalate]
  priorityclasses.*            []                 []                                                              [create bind escalate]
  clusterrolebindings.*        []                 [********************]                                          [patch update delete]
  clusterrolebindings.*        []                 [********************]                                          [patch update delete]
  clusterroles.*               []                 [********************]                                          [patch update delete]
  clusterroles.*               []                 [********************]                                          [patch update delete]
  customresourcedefinitions.*  []                 [********************]                                          [patch update]
  customresourcedefinitions.*  []                 [********************]                                          [patch update]
  customresourcedefinitions.*  []                 [********************]                                          [patch update]

$ kubectl describe  clusterrolebinding custom-bind
Name:         custom-bind
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  custom-access
Subjects:
  Kind            Name    Namespace
  ----            ----    ---------
  ServiceAccount  user  serviceaccounts

